# Does increasing the number of iterations affect log-lik, AIC etc.?

Tags: iteration, lme4

Whenever I try to solve a convergence issue in one of my `glmer` models with the help of a different optimizer, I repeat the entire model optimization procedure with the new optimizer. That is, I re-run all the models I've computed so far with the new optimizer and again conduct comparisons with `anova ()`. I do this because as far as I know different optimizers may lead to differences in AICs and log-lik ratios for one and the same model, making comparisons between two models that use different optimizers problematic.

In my most recent analysis, I've increased the number of iterations with `optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)` to avoid convergence errors. I'm now wondering whether this can also lead to differences in AIC/log-lik etc. for one and the same model? Is it equally problematic to compare two models that differ with regard to the inclusion of the `optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)` argument?

I actually thought that increasing the number of iterations would simply lead to longer computation times (rather than different results), but I was unable to verify this online. Any hint/explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should be fine. As long as the models were fit with the same number of observations you should be able to compare them using the AIC. Hopefully someone else can comment on the nuances of the computations of the AIC itself, but I just fit a bunch of models with the same formula and dataset and different number of max iterations, getting the AIC each time. It didn't change as a function of the iterations. The iterations are just the time the model fitting process can take to maximize the likelihood, which for complex models can be tricky. Once a model is fit, and has converged on an answer, the number of iterations shouldn't change anything about the model itself.

If you look at this question, the top answer explains the AIC quite well:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232465/how-to-compare-models-on-the-basis-of-aic

Comment: Thank you so much - this is very helpful :)! This was also what I gathered! (And yes, the models were fit with the same n of observations.)